# How to remove color tags in pantheon-files?

Tags: pantheon-files

How to remove this? Because, i don't need this.

[image: Color tags]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way of removing the color-tag plugin using the UI I am afraid. One way removing it would be to move the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.files/plugins/core/pantheon-files-ctag.plug` into a new subfolder of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.files/plugins` called e.g. `disabled`.  You would need to open Files as administrator to do this.  You may find the plug reappearing if you update Files and it definitely will if you reinstall. A way of disabling unwanted plugins with a significant overhead might be a feature you want to request at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues

Comment: Thanks! It's work.